# Like Function with Firebase/Swift

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `Firebase` and try to implement `Like Button` such as Facebook or Instagram.

I have written some code , but I have noticed that the number of likes sometimes increase by more than one like when user taps the like button many times, very fast.

Code...

```
func handleLike(likeButton: UIButton, numberLabel: UILabel) {    
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    if let photoId = photo?.id {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let photoRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("likes").child(photoId)
        photoRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "LikeFilled"), forState: .Normal)
                likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
                ref.child("users").child(uid).child("likes").child(photoId).setValue(true)
                ref.child("photos").child(photoId).child("likes").child(uid).setValue(true)
                self.photo?.adjustLikes(true)
                if let numberofLikes = self.photo?.numberofLikes {
                    ref.child("photos").child(photoId).child("numberofLikes").setValue(numberofLikes)
                    numberLabel.text = String(numberofLikes) + "Likes"
                }

            } else {
                likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "UNLike"), forState: .Normal)
                likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(r:143, g: 150, b: 163), forState: .Normal)
                ref.child("users").child(uid).child("likes").child(photoId).removeValue()
                ref.child("photos").child(photoId).child("likes").child(uid).removeValue()
                self.photo?.adjustLikes(false)
                ref.child("photos").child(photoId).child("numberofLikes").setValue(self.photo?.numberofLikes)
                if let numberofLikes = self.photo?.numberofLikes {
                    ref.child("photos").child(photoId).child("numberofLikes").setValue(numberofLikes)
                    numberLabel.text = String(numberofLikes) + "Likes"
                }
            }
            }, withCancelBlock: nil)
    }
} 

class Photo: NSObject {

func adjustLikes(addLike: Bool) {
    if addLike {
        numberofLikes = numberofLikes! + 1
    } else {
        numberofLikes = numberofLikes! - 1
    }
}
}
```

How can I implement synchronous function such as LIKE/UNLIKE function ?
I thought that I could use `with CompletionBlock`, but I couldn't implement it with `.observeSingleEventOfType`...

I appreciate any help...

Comment: Give your JSON tree structure as text not as image

Answer (score 1):

I have been also trying to implement like counter but using parse as baas. The best solution i have adopted is to don't update the counter value on server directly but set a time out when the time out finish update on server with last state (liked or not):

1. Check if liked or not and invert the like state : `liked = !liked`
2. Update the local Counter Correspondingly : `liked ? likeCounter++ : likeCounter--`
3. Update The UI : `likeLabel.text = "\(likeCounter)"`

Finally check if there is a timer set to update server like state :

```
if(likeTimer != nil) {
        // Stop current operation
        likeTimer.invalidate()
}
//Setup a set time out 1s func
likeTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLikeCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func updateLikeCounter(){
   //if liked == true and the like operation is not submitted to server ==> increment like counter on server . else do nothing
   //if like == false and a like operation have been submitted to server (user is in the list of users who like the image) ==> decrement like counter on server . else do nothing 
}
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it. That's the very idea that I did not think of. I really appreciate that.